# String.split() side effects, or regexp mistake?

Tags: java, string

I try to parse string `"[01.02.2016][0][]"` to `"01.02.2016"` and `"0"` by `String.split(regexp)` method, using next regexp: `"[\\[(*?)\\]]"` or `"\\[|\\]"` or `"[\\[+\\]]"`.

But method always returned Array `["", "01.02.2016","","0"]`.
Is normal result for `String.split(regexp)`, or my mistake in regexp?

Comment: `String.split(regexp)` *splits* the String based on *delimiter*, it doesn't *parse* the String. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to match and get matched groups from String

Comment: and yes, that is indeed expected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [TheLostMind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/thelostmind). Using [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) a possible solution could be:

```
String s = "[01.02.2016][0][]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[[^\\]]*\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("part = " + m.group());
}
```

output

```
part = [01.02.2016]
part = [0]
part = []
```

**edit** As noted by [Kuzeko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5973334/kuzeko). If you want to get the Parts without the surrounding brackets `[]` amend the code as follow.

```
String s = "[01.02.2016][0][]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]"); // pattern changed
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("part = " + m.group(1)); // accessed group changed
}
```

output

```
part = 01.02.2016
part = 0
part =
```

**edit** To the second part of your question. `String.split` worked as you requested it to work. See the examples below

`[\\[(*?)\\]]` - use as delimitter any character of `[(*?]` (because they are grouped within `[...]`

```
String s = "1[2(3*4?5)6]7";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\\[(*?)\\]]")));
// output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

`\\[|\\]` - use as delimitter `[` or `]`

```
String s = "1[2]3";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\[|\\]")));
// output
[1, 2, 3]
```

`[\\[+\\]]` - use as delimitter any character of `[+]` (because they are grouped within `[...]`

```
String s = "1[2[3+4]5";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\\[+\\]]")));
// output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Traling empty fields are omitted when you don't specify a result threshold.

```
String s = ",1,2,,,";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(",")));
// output
[, 1, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(",", 5)));
// output
[, 1, 2, , ,]
```

For an explanation how this works in detail have a look in the API [String.split(s,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: Or you can replace `*` with `+` if you don't want to find empty pairs of brackets.

Comment: You should use the `()` to group and return only the text inside the brackets as OP needs

Comment: Thnks, i uses Pattern and Matcher, but also wanted to know is that expected result of String.split().

Comment: @SubOptimal, nice. Thnks, i undestand my delusion. Just confused behavior between split method and real regexp. Maybe it because method declaration are: public String[] split(String regex).

Answer (score 0):

The `String.split` tries to find matches of your pattern and split accordingly.
An example of use is that you want to split a string based on comma and semicolon.
In that case you would use as "regexp" `,|;`.

In your case if you use, for example `"\\[|\\]"` it means that it split when it find either an open bracket or a closed one.
Hence, you have empty before the first open bracket, the date after the same and before the closed one, empty between closed and open, and so on.

As @TheLostMind suggests, you want to use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` and groups instead.

Answer (score -3):

### try this [Problem Solved]

```
String name ="[01.02.2016][0][]";
        name=name.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", " ").trim();
        String[] x1=name.split("[^\\d.]");
        System.out.println("name = "+x1[0]);
        System.out.println("name = "+x1[2]);
```

#### output

```
name = 01.02.2016
name = 0
```

Comment: Your solution is by far not optimal. First you replace everything which does not match with either 'digits' or a period with a space. Essentially, you're replacing the ']' and '[' characters with a space. Then you trim it, removing the spaces from the beginning and end of the string.
Then you make another regexp pass to split the string on anything that does not match 'digits' or a period. Essentially, you're splitting on the space characters, thus why x1[1] is an empty string.
Look at the above solutions which show a better understanding of regexps.